# Multiple values in a regular expression in Unix - Multiple substrings possibles into a string of a expression

Tags: regex, shell, unix, grep, aix

I have a problem with a regular expression due to I have to accept multiple possible values for some files in Unix. If the pattern matches is Case A, else Case B. Ie:

```
echo a | grep "^[a\|b\|c]$"
echo a | grep "^[b\|a\|c]$"
echo b | grep "^[a\|b\|c]$"
echo c | grep "^[a\|b\|c]$"

echo typeA | grep "^[typeA\|typeB]$"
echo typeA | grep "^[typeA\|typeB\|c]$"
echo typeA | grep "^[typeA\|typeB]$"
echo typeA | grep "^[typeA\|typeB]$"
```

With these examples, I get the following output

```
a
a
b
c

(empty)
(empty)
(empty)
(empty)
```

I really don't know why in the cases 5, 6, 7 and 8, I don't get an answer.

"Original code":

```
ls *.CTL > $ArchivosControl
for i in $(cat $ArchivosControl); do
    pattern=`echo $i | grep '^fixedvalues[0-9]\{7\}_[OptionA1\|OptionA2\|OptionA3]_fixedvalues_[OptionB1\|OptionB2]\.CTL$'`
    if [ "$pattern" != "" ]; then
        Cantidad_Control=$((Cantidad_Control+1))
        echo $pattern >> $List
    else
        echo "It doesn't match for $i"
    fi
done
```

**EDIT 2016-10-13 20:30**

The answer of kennytm works in Linux:

```
echo t | grep "^[typeA\|typeB]$"
```

but I need that it works in Unix Server (AIX specifically)

```
echo P_typeA_123 | grep "^P_(typeA\|typeB)_[0-9]\{3\}$"
```

The optional text is into a major expression that I need to validate.

**EDIT 2016-10-14 14:52**

At the last of the string, I would like to search if exists a 'C' or 'H'. Should I use () or []. IE:

```
echo P_typeA_123N | grep -E "^P_(typeA\|typeB)_[0-9]\{3\}[N|H]$"
echo P_typeA_123N | grep -E "^P_(typeA\|typeB)_[0-9]\{3\}(N|H)$"
```

I has proove both options and I can't choose one.

PD: 'grep -E' is equal to 'egrep'? I can't find the difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the wrong brackets.

```
$ #                   ↓↓            ↓↓
$ echo typeA | grep "^\(typeA\|typeB\)$"
typeA
```

The `[]` is used to construct character classes. `[typeA\|typeB]` means matching one of the character `t`, `y`, `p`, `e`, `A`, `\`, `|`, etc.

```
$ echo t | grep "^[typeA\|typeB]$"
t
```

What you want is grouping, which in Basic Regular Expression syntax is represented by `\( … \)`.

Comment: Are all the metacharacters in BRE escaped, and non-escaped for literals?

Comment: @sln No, `[]`, `.`, `*`, `^` and `$` are special. `\(\)` and `\{\}` need to be escaped. The `\?`, `\+` and `\|` are actually not part of BRE, but both `grep` on Linux and OS X support it.

Comment: It works fine in Linux Server, how can I do this in a Unix Server?

Comment: @Angel: My answer uses `\( ... \)`, not `[ ... ]` 

Comment: I copied the previous code, but I proove the rigth code with \(...\), sorry

Comment: @Angel It is `\( ... \)` with the backslashes, not `( ... )`. Or change to use `egrep` if you don't want to type all the backslashes.

Comment: Yeah, I use 'echo $file_name | egrep "^...\(optionA\|optionB\|optionC\)...$" ', withouth the single quotes to validate the name of the file. In the section edited, I add an example more specific of my case

Comment: @Angel If you use `egrep`, don't include the backslashes. Please check http://www.regular-expressions.info/posix.html.

Answer (score 0):

Change your line to the following:

```
echo typeB | egrep "^typeA|typeB$"
```

Comment: Please see my section edited, due to I have modified my question to explain better my case. I need a expression with three possible values into my regex, that need other patterns

Answer (score 0):

Square brackets generally mean a character set, not a whole pattern.  So:

> grep '^[abc]$'

Would match any line that consists entirely of exactly ONE a, b, or c only.

OTOH:

> egrep '^(abc|def)$'

...would match exactly the line 'abc' OR the line 'def' and nothing else.

Alternation (which is what | does) is supported only by extended regexes, so use egrep instead of grep.  See also [alternation ref](http://regular-expressions.mobi/alternation.html).

Comment: Please see my section edited, due to I have modified my question to explain better my case. I need a expression with three possible values into my regex, that need other patterns.